# JavaFX 2 - ProgressIndicator overlay on a GridPane

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, progress

In `JavaFX 2` you can use a `ProgressInidicator` to show that some background task is in progress.

I would like to show `ProgressIndicator` centered on top of a `GridPane`, so that it overlays the `GridPane`. In Swing you can use `GlassPane` for this. How do I do it in JavaFX 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use StackPane. For info about layouts see [Built-in Layout Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm).

Comment: I am wondering if it would be advisable to always use a StackPane as the main pane and wrap any other built-in layout within!? At least in my case where I want to show ProgressIndicator overlayed on the pane where the action has been invoked it seems to make sense. Thanks for your answer.